# how to take screenshot of specific area on the screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image]

I want to extract an image of a specific area on the screen? I have the x, y, height, and width. Anybody knows how can I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe you can take a screenshot with `RepaintBoundary` and then crop the PNG?

Answer (score 1):

well i don't know about x and y but what you can do is screen shot of specific widgets with package `screenshot`, [link](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)

this package capture widgets as Images, even if they are not rendered on screen.

Step 1: create a controller

```
ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
```

Step 2: wrap widgets with `Screenshot()`

```
Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Text("This text will be captured as image"),
),
```

step 3: Take the screenshot by calling capture method. This will return a Uint8List

```
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
    //Capture Done
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
    });
}).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Through RepaintBoundary widget you can take screenshot of specific area which you want. I put one example at here which I performed in my project. Please go with it. I hope it will helpful to you surely.

Declare globalkey first...

```
 GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
```

Then wrap your widget with RepaintBoundary like below with use of this globalKey.

```
 RepaintBoundary(
            key: globalKey,
            child: Obx(() {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(mainController.imageName.value))),
                height: 390,
                width: 390,
                child: Stack(
                  children: generatedNameWidgets,
                ),
              );
            })),
```